# Some questions from typescript union type

Tags: typescript

I understand that the union type in ts can allow variables to have multiple types.

```
type Test1 = never | any; 
// Any is the top-level type  
// Test1 = any
type Test2 = "123" | string;
// String is the collection of all strings
// Test2 = string
```

Type `T=A | B`, when A and B are combined
When A ("broad type") contains B ("specific type"), A ("broad type") will be concluded.

Then when I apply the conclusion of "object union", I have questions
For parent-child type.

```
interface A1 {
    name: string
}
interface A2 extends A1 {
    age: number
}

type Test3 = A2 | A1;
 
// According to the conclusion, A2 is broader than A1, Test3 = A2
// Not equal to A2
/* Here I explain that when the value corresponding to Test3 is {name: "??"}, 
the mandatory item age attribute type in A2 type is unsafe
/


// According to the above explanation, I try to add options to A2. Will the result be different?
type Test4 = A1 | Partial<A2>;
// but, Not equal to A2 ?


type TypeKeys = keyof Test3;
// Why do I get such a result when I try to get the key
// TypeKeys = "name"
```

**There are also questions when the application function returns**

```
const record: Test3 = {
    name: 'name',
    age: 20
} 

const record2: Test3 = {
    name: 'name'
}

// Finally, I use Test3 type for function return
const fn = (): Test3 => record;

const da = fn();
da.name
da.age // The type shown here is unsafe
// Property 'age' does not exist on type 'Test3'.
// Property 'age' does not exist on type 'A1'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a conceptual difference between `Test2` and `Test3`:

- `"123"` exists within the `string` set already, i.e. `"123"` **is** a subset of the `string` set. So this union can effectively be collapsed into the `string` set
- `A1` **is not** a subset of `A2` and vice versa, although this may seem counterintuitive at first glance:

  - `A1` is an object with a single property `name: string`
  - `A2` is an object with two properties `name: string` and `age: number`
  - There is no object that can be defined that can satisfy both of these definitions at the same time, therefore when you write `A1 | A2`, the best the compiler can resolve to is that it could be either `A1` **or** `A2`, but certainly not both.
  - Note: This property is actually very powerful and allows us to leverage things like [`discriminated unions`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html#discriminating-unions)

---

When you define `record` and `record2`, you are doing the following:

- `record` and `record2` are annotated as `Test3`, which is equivalent to `A1 | A2`.
- You pass in an object of the shape of `A2` to `record`, which the compiler is perfectly happy with as this is a valid `A1 | A2`. Importantly it is not that `record` becomes `A2` under the hood, it is still `A1 | A2`
- You pass in an object of the shape of `A1` to `record2`, which the compiler is perfectly happy with as this is a valid `A1 | A2`.
- I find it easier to visualise if you imagine the variables defined as `let` instead of `const`; as long as the variable is assigned with something that is of the shape of `A1` or `A2` during its lifetime, the compiler will remain happy (even if it starts as `A2` it could be `A1` in future etc)

When all is said and done, despite the contents of the objects in `record` and `record2` obviously being `A2` and `A1` respectively to us, because of the annotation `Test3` it is impossible for the compiler to deduce whether the underlying object is `A1` or `A2`. All it can infer about `Test3` is that regardless of the current value, it will have a `name: string` property. It cannot know whether the `age: number` property is present or missing as that would depend on knowledge about whether the object is `A1` or `A2`.

---

A common solution to this problem is to "unpack" the type using a [`type guard`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-guards-and-differentiating-types), for example:

```
function isA2(record: Test3): record is A2 {
  return (record as A2).age !== undefined;
}

function someFn() {
  const someVariable: Test3 = { name: 'someName' };

  if (isA2(someVariable)) {
    someVariable // A2
    someVariable.name // valid
    someVariable.age // valid
  }
  else {
    someVariable // A1
    someVariable.name // valid
    someVariable.age // invalid
  }
}
```

This explicitly informs the compiler what the shape of the underlying type is using a runtime construct, so even if the variable's value were to change, it would still be able to guarantee type safety.

---

It should now hopefully make sense why the compiler did not accept accessing a property called `age` from a variable typed `Test3` in your `fn` definition.

```
const record: Test3 = {
    name: 'name',
    age: 20
}
const fn = (): Test3 => record;
const da = fn();

da.name // valid, this property definitely exists
da.age // invalid, this property may or may not exist
```

The following alternatives would all be valid

```
const newRecord1: A2 = {
    name: 'name',
    age: 20
}
const fn1 = (): A2 => newRecord1;
const da1 = fn1();

da1.name // valid
da1.age // valid
```

```
const newRecord2: Test3 = {
    name: 'name',
    age: 20
}
const fn2 = (): Test3 => newRecord2;
const da2 = fn2();

if (isA2(da2)) {
  da2.name // valid
  da2.age // valid
}
```

https://tsplay.dev/w1AeGw

Answer (score 0):

**When you use keyof Test3, TypeScript is trying to get the keys of the type Test3 which is A2 , so it gives you back the keys that are in A2 interface, which is "name" only.**

you can solve this by using a type-guard, checking if the returned object is having the property of age,

```
const fn = (): Test3 => {
    if(record.hasOwnProperty('age')){
        return record;
    }
    return record2;
}
```